# find the expected value of the joint probability function?

Tags: probability

I have just finished a final and would like to know answer to one of the questions and if I got it right.

The question is:

> "Let $X$ and $Y$ be continuous random variables such that:
>
> $$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} (10-x\,y^2)/64 & :2 \leq x \leq 10 \;\land\; 0\leq y \leq 1\\[1ex] 0 & :\textsf{ otherwise } \end{cases}$$
>
> Compute $\mathsf E[Y]$."

How would I find the expected value of $Y$?

Comment: What did you attempt? Also please format with [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: One way is to integrate $\frac{y}{64}(10-xy^2)$ over the rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must get the marginal probability density function of $ y $ as,

$$
f_{y} (y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{x,y} (x,y) dx \\
= \int_{2}^{10} \frac{1}{64} \left( 10 - xy^{2} \right) dx
$$

and then compute the expected value as,

$$
\text{E}[Y] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y f_{y} (y) dy \\
= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{64} \left( 80y - 48 y^{3} \right) dy
$$